# REST-API database-relationships back-referencing

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express

I’m developing a REST-API with NodeJS and Express with a MySQL-backend. The existing database has a lot of 1:n relationships and I’m struggling to find the right URI-scheme for these specific cases.

A simple example:

```
user {
    id 
    name
}
comment {
    id
    text
    user_id
}
```

Now, when I try to get the a list of all users, my uri would be: `/users`
- for one specific user: `/user/{id}`
- data for one specific user: `/user/{id}/name`
- for a list of all comments: `/comment`
- for one specific comment: `/comment/{id}`
- data for one specific comment: `/comment/{id}/text`

Now, the part where I’m struggling.
There is a 1:n relationship between user and comment. One user can have multiple comments, one comment belongs to one user. I want to implement something like a ‘back-reference’, so that when I access the data (meaning one specific field) for one specific comment, I can also get the information about the user the comment ‘belongs’ to.
The API doesn't know about these relationships, I'm also not using an ORM, so I have to hard code the information about the relationships somewhere anyway.
I already implemented a route where I can make a request on `/comment/{id}/user_id` where I redirect the request to `/user/{id}` with the id the comment belongs to. But this would be the same request for when I just want to get the user id for that comment, not the whole dataset for the user.
I've read a lot about the REST architecture and roy fielding always talks about making the API "browsable" or "explorable". One approach I came upon was adding a reference uri to the linked dataset, in my example that would mean expanding the `user_id` field to something like this :

```
user_id {
    id:id
    ref:/user/id
}
```

The results I'm getting from the database are much more complex than that and extracting the respective fields and adding this information seems like a bit much to do for this ‘simple’ problem.

I don't know if I'm missing something here, I'm developing this API for a project on which I also write a paper about and I try to follow the rules of the REST architecture as much as I can, but I'm a bit stuck right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about publishing the comments "under" the user resources like this:

```
/user/{userid}
/user/{userid}/comments/{commentid}
```

Note, that you don't have to publish "database rows" one-to-one in a REST API. Indeed, this is usually frowned upon by REST people.

Also note, you don't have to publish each attribute of a resource as a resource. The resource `/user/{userid}` could very well return a complex (json, xml, etc.) representation that includes all the necessary data. Of course there are reasons to do it your way, for example I would make the text of a comment a separate resource if it is available in pdf, text, html, or in other formats which I don't control.

A minor point about Fielding's "browsable" API: What he means is that these resources reference each other through links in the returned data representations. Comments would reference the users (link to user), and users should reference their comments (links to comments). The client should never have to "guess" or "construct" an URI on its own, it should "browse" resources by following links only!

Comment: In my project, calling something like /user/id will return the whole database-row for the user with that id in JSON, which indeed is a pretty complex representation. i just take the id and fire a SQL-request and return the result in JSON. why is this frowned upon by REST people? what you said about Fielding is exactly where I'm stuck. i would love to implement links in the respective fields, but with the complex dataset i get from the database it doesn't seem practicable

Comment: You don't have to pipe the database directly through a resource unmodified. Get the data from the database, and enrich it, at least with links. If that is unpractical, then you might want to redesign. Also, you don't *have* to conform to REST. A lot of projects just do JSON over HTTP, without links. That is fine as long it is a conscious decision.